# jQuery UI Sortable: Prevent horizontal scrolling with connected lists between full height columns

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm building a web application with two full-height columns using Flexbox in Bootstrap v4. Both columns contain a connected sortable list, which can be sorted using jQuery UI Sortable.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100 d-flex flex-column p-0">

<div class="row flex-grow-1 p-3">

<div class="row flex-grow-1 p-3">
  <div class="col-4 mh-100 full-height-col">

    <ul class="list-group sortable-container sortable-connect">
      <li class="list-group-item">Item 1</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="col-8 mh-100 full-height-col">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4 mb-3">

        <ul class="list-group sortable-container sortable-connect">
          <li class="list-group-item">Item A</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
.sortable-container {
     min-height: 2rem;
}
.full-height-col {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $(".sortable-connect").sortable({
        connectWith: ".sortable-connect"
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

Whenever I'm moving an item from the left list to the right list, the div scrolls horizontally and all remaining items move out of the window.

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mwx46/xqa46bzn/).

Any idea on how to prevent the left list from scrolling horizontally?

Comment: you could use *draggable* and *droppable* right?

Comment: What do you mean? I need both lists to be sortable...

Comment: I figured that it works fine if I remove `overflow-y: scroll;` from the .full-height-col class. However, if I do so the list will not scroll vertically if there are many items in it.

Comment: yeah, sort of... but I got to think that you were trying to implement drag and drop from one list to the other...

Comment: That is what I want. My problem is that I cannot prevent the left list from scrolling to nowhere everytime I move an item from the left list to the right one (see Fiddle).

Answer (score -1):

You need to set sortable "scroll" to false.

This will prevent the container from scrolling when dragging a sortable element.

Next you will want to use `helper: 'clone'` along with `appendTo: 'body'` to bring the sortable element to the front; when your sortable div has a scroll, the sortable elements will float behind everything else, using a helper will bring it to the front.

```
$(function() {
  $(".sortable-connect").sortable({
    connectWith: ".sortable-connect",
    scroll: false,
    helper: 'clone',
    appendTo: 'body',
    start: function(event,ui) {
      ui.helper.addClass('ui-helper');
    }
  }).disableSelection();
});
```